# on duplicate key to update just one string

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the following code for an inventory system.

```
$barc = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['barc']);
$cant = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cant']);
$com = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['com']);

$sql="INSERT INTO inventario (barc, cant, com)
VALUES ('$barc', '$cant', '$com')"
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE barc=barc,cant=cant + $cant,com=com;

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";
```

im trying to make the if BARC exist, it adds old "cant" + new "cant" but mantain all the other data.

but im getting error. i appreciate all help

Comment: Your `ON DUPLICATE KEY` line is outside the string.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
INSERT INTO inventario (barc, cant, com)
    VALUES ('$barc', '$cant', '$com')"
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cant = concat(coalesce(cant, ''), coalesce($cant, ''));
```

Apart from putting the entire SQL statement in a single string, the concatenation function in MySQL is `concat()`.  I added the `coalesce()`s to handle `NULL` values.  Columns not included will not change.